# S3 create bucket fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, serverless-framework

I'm trying to create a serverless project which deploys a CloudFormation and as a part of that it tries to create an S3 bucket. But this fails due to following error:

```
15:23:25 UTC+0550   CREATE_FAILED       AWS::S3::Bucket ServerlessDeploymentBucket  API: s3:CreateBucket Access Denied
15:23:24 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::S3::Bucket ServerlessDeploymentBucket
```

I've tried to create an S3 bucket with command `aws s3api create-bucket --bucket my-bucket --region us-west-2` which successfully creates the bucket. I'm not sure why I'm getting access denied while creating the S3 bucket via serverless. What could be the issue here?

Here's my `serverless.yml` file

```
service: auth-service-gs

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python2.7
  stage: dev2-gs-1
  region: us-west-2
  profile: mfa
  environment:
    DB_HOST: "DB_HOST"
    DB_USER: "root"
    DB_PASS: "<password>"
    LOG_LEVEL: "DEBUG"


functions:
  login:
    handler: handler.login
    events:
       - http:
           path: /api/v1/login
           method: post
           cors: true
```

I deploy the service using `$serverless deploy`
Also, content of `~/.aws/credentials`

```
[mfa]
aws_access_key_id = <ACESS_KEY>
aws_secret_access_key = <SECRET_KEY>
aws_session_token = <SESSION ID>
```

Which I got by running

`$ aws sts get-session-token --serial-number arn:aws:iam::<number>:mfa/<username> --token-code 123456`

Comment: Check if Serverless is using an IAM role which doesn't have necessary permissions to create S3 bucket to run the CloudFormation

Comment: Serverless config mentions the pair of keys, there is no explicit mention of roles. I used the same pair of keys and I was able to create the bucket.

Comment: What is the IAM policy attached the Lambda function?

Comment: @strongjz can you guide me on how to check that. I am using an account for which there's one role for which has administrative access to all services. Do I need to explicitly put permission in serverless config file?

Comment: When you create the lambda function you have to create an Execution role. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/intro-permission-model.html#lambda-intro-execution-role

Comment: @GaneshSatpute Update the post with `serverless.yml` and steps when you run the `deploy` command

Comment: @strongjz The document link you've provided is applicable when I'm using existing S3 resource. But in my case serverless will create a new S3 bucket when we deploy it. Let me know, if I'm wrong.

Comment: Hi @ChackoMathew. I've updated the answers with details you requested. Let me know if you need other info.

Answer (score 3):

Your process role will need IAM permission, either at the role or at the user level, depending on your implementation.

Assuming you want the process to create and have all permisions to the bucket, you would need something like this:

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: But if that was the case, I wouldn't have been able to create the S3 bucket using the AWS command line, right?

Comment: Additionally, the process creates the new S3 bucket itself.

Comment: where does this go?